# how to copy previous value in array (string)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So how we can make a function that will take arrays of string like `const numbers = ['1','2','0','3','0']`

and change it for `const changedNumbers = ['1','1','2','2','0','3','3','0']`

Comment: Under what conditions is the previous value duplicated? Why aren't the 0s duplicated too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If `'0'` return `'0'`, else return an array with two current string. Flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const numbers = ['1','2','0','3','0']

const result = [].concat(...numbers.map((s) => +s ? [s, s] : s));

console.log(result);
```